# Confusion about the proof of if $g$ is an odd primitive rood mod $p^a$, then $g$ is also a primitive root mod $2p^a$

Tags: number-theory

My teacher said the fact as obvious and left it at that. I have found some proofs online, but do not understand them. Could someone help me understand the proofs? I have written the steps I don't understand in brackets.

Let $m=ord_{2p^e}$. $g$ is coprime to $2p^e$, so $m |\phi(2p^e)$ [How did they conclude this fact?]. If $g^m \equiv 1 \bmod (2p^e)$, then $g^m \equiv 1 \bmod (p^e)$. Since $g$ is a primitive root $\bmod (p^e)$, therefore $\phi(p^e)|m$ [why did they need to mention $g$ is a primitive root? couldn't we just have used the fact that $g^{\phi(p^e)} \equiv 1 \bmod (p^e)$ and concluded $m=\phi(p^e)$?], so $g$ has order $\phi(2p^e)$ , and is therefore a primitive root.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part note that $g^{\phi(2p^a)} \equiv 1 \pmod{2p^a}$, hence we have that $\phi(2p^a)$ is divisible by the order of $g$, i.e. $m$.

For the second part you need the fact that $g$ is a primitive root. The group of units modulo $p^e$ has $\phi(p^e)$ elements and as $g$ is a generator of it we have that $\phi(p^e)$ is the order of $g$. As in the previous case we have that the order divides $m$, as $g^m \equiv 1 \pmod{p^e}$